# Using Golang, how to read a file contents between 2 characters

Tags: go

So I really want to learn go, however its a much harder and confusing language than I thought it would be. My goal is to write a program that edits a dns file. The first step is to open a file and read it into memory. Ok, that was easily accomplished with ioutil.Readfile. So the next thing I need to do is to read only the SOA or read until you encounter a ")". How on earth would I do this? Here is what the file looks like:

```
example.com.    SOA     dns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
            2001062501 ; serial
            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
            3600       ; retry after 1 hour
            604800     ; expire after 1 week
            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day
```

Ideally the program would start with the line that included "SOA" and end with ")" and also recognize ";". Where should I start with this?

Comment: An interesting primer on lexical scanning in Go can be [viewed here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE). While you probably can do with something simpler, it will show you where to start.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do have a total control is to use `text/scanner` 
Here is an example of your case: 
http://play.golang.org/p/_9LddtB7R9

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)
import "text/scanner"

var dnsRecord = `example.com.    SOA     dns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
            2001062501 ; serial
            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
            3600       ; retry after 1 hour
            604800     ; expire after 1 week
            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day
`

func main() {

    var s scanner.Scanner
    s.Init(strings.NewReader(dnsRecord))
    tok := s.Scan()
    for tok != scanner.EOF {
        // do something with tok
        tok = s.Scan()
        fmt.Println(s.TokenText())
    }

}
```

Otherwise you could use a Regex to match a specific line http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/